# Arrayindexoutofbounds in an 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to get the default null values out of my 2d String array.

I've got this so far.

```
String[][] sterren = new String[12][37];
    int h = 12;
    String leeg = "";       
    while(h > 0){ 
        int b = 37;
        sterren[h][b] = leeg;
        while(b > 0){
            sterren[h][b] = leeg;
            b = b-1;
        }
        h = h-1;
    }
```

with h = height and b = width

When I try to execute this I get an arrayindexoutofbounds 12 on the line `sterren[h][b] = leeg;`. why is that since I clearly made 12 columns and 37 rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new String[12][37]` means that the `length` of each array is `12` and `37`, they can hold 12 and 37 Objects respectively. Because arrays start at index `0` that means they only have indexes `0` - `length - 1`. That means if an array has a length of `12`, it has indexes `0`-`11`. In this example you try adding to index `12` in the outer array and index `37` to the inner arrays (in which their last index is `36`).

To make this work have `h = 11` and `b = 36` and make the `while` loops `while h >=0` and `while b >= 0`.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense thanks! Didn't know that the 0 was counted as an index automatically.

Comment: The first dimension doesn't hold strings at all, but rather holds arrays of strings.  Conceptually it may help to think about it like a table where the first index specifies a row, and the second index specifies a column in that row.

You may prove this by doing the following:

`String[][] table = new String[12][37];
String[] row = table[0];
String value = row[0];`  Java also supports ragged arrays, which means that the second dimension doesn't need to be fixed when the array is created (each row could be a different length).

Comment: @BobbyStJacques Thanks for pointing that out. I was just making a point about the `length` and wrote it too quickly. I'll correct it now.